# CASE STATEMENT + COUNT function not working - SQL Big Query

Tags: sql, count, google-bigquery, case-statement

when i run this code it does not seem to be working in big query...

```
SELECT date,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN product = "fan" AND product color = "white" 
                 THEN product_code ELSE "null" END) AS number_of_whitefans, 
  FROM `radiant-oven-328313.customer_data.customer_purchase` 
 GROUP by date
```

Been trying to run this code many times and i wonder if it's any commas i've missed or just the order of the syntax? i'm running this using bigquery - should i have included a else statement? I've been following the below line of code logic from datacamp so could someone tell me if i've replicated the same thing for my code above with a different data set?

```
SELECT season, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN hometeam_id = 8650 
                       AND home_goal > away_goal
                  THEN match_id END) AS home_wins
       COUNT(CASE WHEN awayteam_id = 8650 
                       AND away_goal > home_goal THEN id END) AS away_wins 
  From match 
 GROUP by season;
```

Comment: Hi - what do you mean by “not working”? Is it erroring (in which case what’s the error message), is it producing the wrong result, or something else?

Comment: `AND product color = "white" ` should be `AND product_color = "white" ` - the only piece I can see to be fixed here

Comment: I think its just `product_color = 'white'` instead of `product color = "white"` and use just `null` instead of "null" to get the right count: `count(case when product = 'fan' and product_color = 'white'  then product_code else null end) as number_of_whitefans`

Comment: `"NULL"` is a string, you want the literal `NULL`, without the quotes.